# In WCF, how are they able to support jagged arrays but not able to support multidimensional arrays?

Tags: wcf, soa, theory

Just curious as to why from an architectural standpoint, WCF web services can handle KnownTypes/Operational Contracts which contain jagged arrays; but are unable to support those that contain multidimensional arrays? Thanks.

Comment: Just a speculation: I bet that no work needs to be done to support jagged arrays since they are just arrays of arrays.  Once you support arrays, jagged arrays comes for free.  Whereas a multidimensional array requires special syntax [,]

Comment: Please describe a multidimensional array using XML Schema.